# What's the best way for a dotnet core app to know if it's being debugged by visual studio in a container or in the traditional way?

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio-debugging

I know I can make visual studio add a new environment variable when it's debugging normally (outside the container), but I'm wondering if there are custom environment variables added by visual studio to the app when it's running inside a docker container. Is a check on environment variables the best method to use?

checking `#if DEBUG` won't work because it's the same in both situations.